# Yii2 translation

Tags: internationalization, yii2

I have Yii2 - advanced template
I kept source language english 
And the target language is french
The system mesages are translated like : 
Yii::t('yii','Update') is translated "Modifier"

But all my custom translations do not work - here is what I did :

modified : backend\config\main.php :

```
    'i18n' => [
        'translations' => [
            'app*' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                'basePath' => '@common/messages',
                'sourceLanguage' => 'en-US',
                'fileMap' => [
                    'app' => 'app.php',
                    'app/error' => 'error.php',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
'language' => 'fr',
```

created : common\config\i18n.php

```
<?php
return [
    'sourcePath' => __DIR__. '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
    'languages' => ['fr-FR','en-EN'], //Add languages to the array for the language files to be generated.
    'translator' => 'Yii::t',
    'sort' => false,
    'removeUnused' => false,
    'only' => ['*.php'],
    'except' => [
        '.svn',
        '.git',
        '.gitignore',
        '.gitkeep',
        '.hgignore',
        '.hgkeep',
        '/messages',
        '/vendor',
    ],
    'format' => 'php',
    'messagePath' => __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'messages',
    'overwrite' => true,
];
```

Sure that I must have mixed up something but I can't find - Some help would be nice !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your configuration looks correct. I assume you have the `fr` folder in your `common/messages` folder for your custom translations.

You need to use `Yii::t('app','your_custom_word');`.

`your_custom_word` should be defined in the `common/messages/fr/app.php` file.

Comment: Thanks for the hint : I generated the folder autmatically with 

    yii message/extract @common/config/i18n.php

Comment: Thanks for the hint : I generated the folder autmatically with "yii message/extract @common/config/i18n.php" and as I setup fr-FR it created the folder fr-FR - I renamed the folder and it works